# Akka.NET Remote Log Aggregation/Collecting

Tags: akka.net

I have a scenario where I have a client (console) application which will be invoked by an enterprise job scheduler (AutoSys). This client sends work to my "Server " (quotes because this could be a cluster). I need to be able to ship log messages from the server to the client for all log messages related to the client's work request. Does the built in logging support this kind of distribution? Can I get some guidance on how I can achieve this?

I see something in the codebase called `LoggingBus`, is this where I need to look?

My core usecase is being able to ship log entries across remote actors.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do in this case is use a built-in logger that supports remote log shipping. Akka.Logging.Serilog and Akka.Logging.NLog both have configurable logging targets that can support this.

I personally think Serilog combined with [Seq](http://getseq.net/) is the best option.